# @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook

Tags: webdriver-io, saucelabs, wdio-v5

Getting an error while running with saucelabs (wdio5).

2019-10-03T15:23:56.763Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook

Error: Could not start Sauce Connect. Exit code 1 signal: null

I have updated @wdio/cli with latest. But still getting the same error.

I expect the test should run in saucelabs.

Answer (score 1):

This is because we need to add sauce username and key as environment variables also in addition to adding them to the configuration files.

```
    const sauceConfig = Object.assign(baseConfig, {
    user: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
    key: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: 'eu',
    maxInstances: 50,
});
exports.config = sauceConfig;
```

Please let me know if this helps or if you have already added it.