# Executing WDIO-Test locally in a docker container throws error: @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose, webdriver-io, wdio-v6

I'm executing a headless e2e-test locally in a docker-container like so:

```
docker-compose up
yarn test
```

I get this error-message at the beginning:

```
ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
TypeError: Cannot read property 'args' of undefined
    at DockerLauncher.onPrepare (C:\myProgs\myWDIOTest\node_modules\wdio-docker-service\lib\launcher.js:30:9)
    at C:\myWDIOTest\myWDIOTest\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\utils.js:24:40
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.runServiceHook (C:\myProgs\myWDIOTest\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\utils.js:21:33)
    at Launcher.run (C:\myProgs\myWDIOTest\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\launcher.js:61:27)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I'm not using the onPrepare-Hook the wdio-configuration-file (see below).

The test carries on and actually finishes successfully every time, just like it's supposed to. At this point simply suppressing this error-message would be a viable solution for me (since this error doesn't compromise the test-results).

There exists a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222404/wdio-cliutils-a-service-failed-in-the-onprepare-hook) for tests run on **saucelabs**, however that won't work for me. But this makes me wonder if I have to look for the solution in my docker-compose-file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210713
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210713
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

This is the contents of my wdio-configuration-file:

```
import BrowserOptions from "./browserOpts";
import CucumberOptions from "./cucumberOpts";

const fs = require('fs');
const wdioParallel = require('wdio-cucumber-parallel-execution');
const reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');
const currentTime = new Date().toJSON().replace(/:/g, "-");
const jsonTmpDirectory = `reports/json/tmp/`;

let featureFilePath = `featureFiles/*.feature`;
let timeout = 30000;

exports.config = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 4444,
    sync: true,
    specs: [
        featureFilePath
    ],
    maxInstances: 1,
    capabilities: [{
        maxInstances: 1,
        browserName: "chrome",
        'goog:chromeOptions': BrowserOptions.getChromeOpts(),
    }],
    logLevel: 'error',
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
     waitforTimeout: timeout,
    connectionRetryTimeout: timeout * 3,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    services: ['docker'],
    framework: 'cucumber',
    reporters: [
        ['cucumberjs-json', {
            jsonFolder: jsonTmpDirectory,
            language: 'de'
        }]
    ],
     cucumberOpts: CucumberOptions.getDefaultSettings(),
     before: function (capabilities, specs) {
        browser._setWindowSize(1024, 768)
    },
    beforeSuite: function (suite) {
        console.log(`Suite "${suite.fullTitle}" from file "${suite.file}" starts`);
    },
    beforeTest: function (test) {
        console.log(`Test "${test.title}" starts`);
    },
    afterTest: function (test) {
        console.log(`Test "${test.title}" finished`);
    },
    onComplete: () => {
        console.log('<<< E2E-TEST COMPLETED >>>\n\n');

        try {
            let consolidatedJsonArray = wdioParallel.getConsolidatedData({
                parallelExecutionReportDirectory: jsonTmpDirectory
            });

            let jsonFile = `${jsonTmpDirectory}report.json`;
            fs.writeFileSync(jsonFile, JSON.stringify(consolidatedJsonArray));

            let options = {
                theme: 'bootstrap',
                jsonFile: jsonFile,
                output: `reports/html/report-${currentTime}.html`,
                reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
                scenarioTimestamp: true,
                launchReport: true,
                ignoreBadJsonFile: true
            };

            reporter.generate(options);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you managed to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I've used the following image instead of my own docker-compose file. Works like a charm.    
image: timbru31/node-chrome:dubnium-slim    
https://hub.docker.com/r/timbru31/node-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose.yml` should work with Webdriverio if you remove `services: ['docker'],` from `wdio.conf.js`.

Based on a comment in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYaLeWgRWy8), `services: ['docker']` is needed if you want wdio to instantiate it's own containers.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this error message specify separate configuration file for wdio docker and leave services with empty array - for me it worked and wdio knows that it should run tests on the container, hope it helped

```
services: [],
```